# How Can I Adjust TextField Placeholder Color : SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

I found that I can customize TextField style in swift like this..

```
struct BottomLineTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        VStack() {
            configuration

            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 1, alignment: .bottom)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to use "underline shape style" text field.

Usage

```
TextField("placeholder", text: $value).textFieldStyle(BottomLineTextFieldStyle()).foregroundColor(.white)
```

However I also wanted to change placeholder color, but I couldn't.

So, **my question is how can I customize textfield's placeholder color**?
please help me and thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the default color of the placeholder yet. However, you can achieve it by writing a custom `TextField` using either `UITextField` or `UITextView`. Here is an example where I created a custom `TextArea` View using `UITextView` where I can set custom color to the placeholder. See my comment below in `makeUIView(_:)`

```
struct TextArea: UIViewRepresentable {
    @State var placeholder: String
    @Binding var text: String

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, placeholder: placeholder)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.text = placeholder

        // Here you can set the color for placeholder text as per your choice. 
        textView.textColor = .lightGray

        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ textView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        if !text.isEmpty {
            textView.text = text
            textView.textColor = .black
        }
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var textArea: TextArea
        var placeholder: String

        init(_ textArea: TextArea, placeholder: String) {
            self.textArea = textArea
            self.placeholder = placeholder
        }

        func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            if textView.textColor == .lightGray {
                textView.text = nil
                textView.textColor = .black
            }
        }

        func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            if textView.text.isEmpty {
                textView.text = placeholder
                textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The above text area can be used in the view like this:

```
 TextArea(placeholder: textValue, text: $textValue)
```

Comment: I understood. thanks. how can I use this Text area? Could you show me example for usage?

Comment: Where do I have to edit this code if I wanted to use "underline" shape textfield instead of box shape?

Comment: You can edit the makeUIView method of TextArea to return UITedtField with your specific needs. Please note, here you’re using UIKit elements instead of SwiftUI elements. You can read more about it here: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit

Answer (score 4):

### SwiftUI 4.0

"Out of the box" with modifiers and background.

```swift
TextField("", text: $name)
    .font(.title2)
    .fontWeight(.medium)
    .frame(height: 55)
    .foregroundColor(.pink)
    .padding(.horizontal)
    .background(
        ZStack{
        Color.white
            if name.count == 0 {
                HStack {
                    Text("Your name here ...")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    Spacer()
              }
             .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
    )
  .cornerRadius(10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> So, my question is how can I customize textfield's placeholder color?

Unfortunately it is not possible to change standard TextField placeholder's color so far. However it is possible to modify it somehow, so, I assume worth posting

In below demo TextField color's modified, Password's one is default.
[image: demo]
[image: demo2]

```
struct BottomLineTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        VStack() {
            configuration
                .colorMultiply(.red)
                .foregroundColor(.red)

            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 1, alignment: .bottom)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The TextFieldStyle is always better solution and actually this was the question. All other solutions have some flaws if you try them, but this one is simple and works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

A simple Z Stack solves all placeholder issues.

Just create a Text() view  behind the TextField

You can do anything with it. Colour, gradients, transitions, etc

```
     @State var text = ""

     ZStack {
          
          if text == "" {
           Text("Placeholder of my choice")
           }

           TextField("", text: $text)
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from iOS 15 no hacks needed to display custom placeholder. Take a look into additional prompt parameter:

```
@available(iOS 15.0, macOS 12.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0, *)
public init(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, text: Binding<String>, prompt: Text?)
```